# Activity Feed for a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, feed

I have a facebook page which I have created. The URL of my facebook page is of the form: https://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Page/12345678901245.

I would like to embed an Activity Feed for this page on a website, according to these instructions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity/

The problem is that the instructions ask for an App ID. From what I understand, Facebook Pages don't have App ID's. So I don't know what to fill in for this.

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

(For the record, I have spent about 1.5 hours hunting down fb documentation and trying various things with absolutely no luck. This is almost always the case whenever I need to integrate fb code in my sites. I am a veteran website developer, and I have never had these kinds of problems embedding other code in my websites, such as paypal and authorize.net, to name just two. I'm curious whether I am alone in experiencing great frustration whenever I need to integrate fb into my sites.)

Comment: If that plugin requires an app id to work – then you will have to create an app first. You can do so under “Apps” menu point on top of the developer section page you linked to.

Comment: Thank you. Okay, I know how to create an app, but how do I indicate that the app that I create is for the facebook page that I created?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer (For those who have a valid fb APP_ID):**

Use facebook social plugin (Like Box) and from the html code, just make the "data-stream" attribute as "true" (Play around with the other options to suit your need).

```
    <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="FB_PAGE_LINK" data-colorscheme="light" 
data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

---

**Long Answer (For those who do not know how to create a fb app) :**

1. **Create a Fb APP:** You need to create a facebook app to use the FB social plugin. It is very simple and you can do it here : https://developers.facebook.com/ by clicking on the "apps" -> "Add a New App" link. Just choose the platform as WWW and give your app a suitable name. You will then need to make your app live. Do so by going to the newly created app's "Status and Review" link and choose "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" as yes.
2. **Use FB Page Plugin (Like Box is no longer supported):**  
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/. Enter your FB page link and from the dropdown that appears on the modal, select your newly created app.

[image]

3. **Use the code (make the "data-show-posts attribute as "true") :**  You are all set, copy the javascript code and the html code. In the html code, just make the "data-stream" attribute as "true".  (Play around with the other options to suit your need).

Generates something like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Cheers!